# CSS animation doesn't play smooth

Tags: css, animation, css-animations

i have a `<button>` element want when this element clicked, button **move down 200px**

using this code in `onclick` event of button to add class, so animation will run:

**JS**

```
function anime() {
    var element = document.getElementById("tagd");
    element.classList.toggle("visible");    
}
```

**HTML**

```
<button onclick="anime()" id="tagd">
```

**CSS**

```
.visible {
    -webkit-animation: myfirst 5s 2; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    -webkit-animation-direction: normal; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    animation: myfirst 5s 2;
    animation-direction: normal;
    position: relative;
}


/* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
@-webkit-keyframes myfirst {
    0%   {top: 0px;}
    25%  {top: 50px;}
    50%  {top: 100px;}
    75%  {top: 150px;}
    100% {top: 200px;}
} 

@keyframes myfirst {
    0%   {top: 0px;}
    25%  {top: 50px;}
    50%  {top: 100px;}
    75%  {top: 150px;}
    100% {top: 200px;}
}
```

---

**So the problem is:**

- Animation going down, then back in first position.
- Animation doesn't play smoothly (if you run it you will see it plays step by step not smooth)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are only changing the position of the button i can advice you the following

```
#tagd{ 
    transition: 5s transform
}
#tagd.visible{
    transform: translateY(200px) 
}
```

The animation is quite simple so using this can increase the readablity from your code. A bit trivial but using 'translate' instead of 'top' also improves the visual performance.

Read more about this if you like:
https://www.paulirish.com/2012/why-moving-elements-with-translate-is-better-than-posabs-topleft/

Comment: i want to play animation after button clicked! if put `transition: 5s transform` inside `#tagd` it will play immediately! wont it?

Comment: @ShahabOuraie I'm glad it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Change these lines in your code putting 1 instead of 2 at the end of these line. Hope it will work for you.

```
-webkit-animation: myfirst 5s 1; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
 animation: myfirst 5s 1;
```

Comment: tnx you sooo much! sorry if i didnt mark yours as answer

Answer (score 0):

Add the property `will-change: top` to `.visible` class